# Determination of rank in Wilcoxon Signed Test

Tags: statistics

When 2 values, say -5 and +5 appears and the current allocation of rank is to be 10, we split the rank to those two as 10.5 each. And the next rank will be 12. Now if there are 3 values with magnitude 5, then what will be the ranks?

Answer (score 0):

The allocations will be 10 and 11 for the two values of 5. The mean of 10 and 11 will be 10.5. So each of them will have 10.5 as rank. The rank of the next higher value will be 12 as usual. Now if there are three 5's, then the ranks allocated will be 10, 11 and 12. The mean of 10, 11 and 12 is 11. So each of them will have 11 as rank. The next higher value will have 13 as rank.